# Formatting date to 2017-06-21T12:33:47.879 format

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatetime

In DB I have `TIMESTAMP` datatype like `17/06/21 12:33:47,879000000` and I would like to select in format `2017-06-21T12:33:47.879`

Edit:
I tried `to_char(MODIFIED_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF')` but  getting

`2010-11-12 11:47:50:294000`. How can I add this 'T' and cut these `'0'` at the end of milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such a formatting model :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( systimestamp ,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS ts
  FROM dual;

 TS
 -----------------------
 2020-08-26T09:51:25.600016
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( timestamp'2017-06-21 12:33:47.879000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF' )  
    AS ts
  FROM dual;

 TS
 -----------------------
 2017-06-21T12:33:47.879000000
```

for a spesific date and time.

Alternatively use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( timestamp'2017-06-21 12:33:47.879000000', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS ts,
       CAST( timestamp'2017-06-21 12:33:47.879000000' AS TIMESTAMP(3) ) As ts2
  FROM dual;

 TS                        TS2
 -----------------------   -----------------------
 2017-06-21T12:33:47.879   2017-06-21T12:33:47.879
```

to get precision set to `3` for milliseconds portion.

Comment: is there any possibility to cut these '0' at the end of miliseconds?